# org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Date parameter 'startTime' is not present

Tags: java, spring, date

I've a GET request that sends a date in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format to a Rest Controller.

**Code :**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/{startTime}/{endTime}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)

    public @ResponseBody Object load(@RequestParam(value="startTime")  @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") Date startTime,@RequestParam(value="endTime") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") Date endTime) throws Exception {
        logger.info("GET ALL APPOINTMENTS");
        SuccessResponse<List<TnAppointment>> resp = new SuccessResponse<List<TnAppointment>>();
        try
        {
            Collection<TnAppointment> sequenceCollection = appointmentDelegate.load(startTime, endTime);
            List<TnAppointment> appointmentList = new ArrayList<TnAppointment>(sequenceCollection); 
            resp.setList(appointmentList);
            if(resp.getList().isEmpty())
            {
                String localizedErrorMessage = messageSource.getMessage("appointments.nodata.found", null, currentLocale);
                return new EmptySuccessResponse(localizedErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception de)
        {
            de.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

I am getting the following Error

```
  2015-02-02 16:23:59,709 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.Object com.**.ui.restcontroller.appointment.AppointmentController.load(java.util.Date,java.util.Date) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date for value '2012-06-10 17:00:06'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse '2012-06-10 17:00:06'
2015-02-02 16:23:59,709 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'myExceptionHandler'
```

I am using the following url for this method

```
http://localhost:**/**/***/appointments/2012-06-10 17:00:06/2012-06-10 17:27:50
```

How can I make the controller to accept this format of DateTime?

Comment: `value="/{startTime}/{endTime}"`, here `startTime` and `endTime` are your `path variables`, remove `@RequestParam` and use `@PathVariable`

Comment: Just a suggestion, extract the date-time pattern to some constant or system settings property, it is not nice to have it hard-coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value="/{startTime}/{endTime}"`, here `startTime` and `endTime` are your path variables, remove `@RequestParam` and use `@PathVariable`.

> @PathVariable is to obtain some placeholder from the uri (Spring call
>   it an URI Template) — [see Spring Reference Chapter 16.3.2.2 URI
>   Template Patterns](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)
>
> @RequestParam is to obtain an parameter — [see Spring Reference Chapter
>   16.3.3.3 Binding request parameters to method parameters with @RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)

small example -

Assume this Url

> http://localhost:8080/MyApp/user/1234/invoices?date=12-05-2013 (to get
>   the invoices for user 1234 for today)

// here `1234` is mapped to `userId` as a path variable

// `date` is mapped as a `request param`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/{userId}/invoices", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Invoice> listUsersInvoices(
            @PathVariable("userId") int user,
            @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) Date dateOrNull) {
  ...
}
```

Also correct pattern to use - `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Hi ankur_singhal. I am still getting the error. Updated my question with the latest error.

Comment: @NNR This is because you are using wrong pattern, use this instead `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, look for uppercase `HH`

Comment: @NNR just a suggestion, debug and you will learn yourself, serach in google, you will find best links. :)